# Where are Google cloud task queues endpoints located and can someone use nodejs child process instead?

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine, task-queue, google-tasks-api

I have a nodejs on Google app engine server but I need to do some background tasks immediately after sending response to user. I have been using the sample code below with nodejs `child-process` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288452/node-js-express-respond-immediately-to-client-request-and-continue-tasks-in-n) but it only works well when tested locally but does not run in google app engine.

```js
let {fork} = require('child_process');
const forked = fork('./worker.js');

router.post('/endpoint', (req, res) => {
    let options = req.body.options;
    let isResponded = false;
    async_helper.doWork(options).then((s) => {
        let reply = JSON.stringify(s);
        isResponded = true;
       res.status(200).send(reply).end();
       return null
    }).then(value => {
    //This is the long task of sending email
        forked.send(value);
        return null
    }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
        if (!isResponded) {
            let errr = err;
            res.status(500).send('Failed').end();
        }
        return null
    });
});
```

Which is the best way of implementing  such tasks in a **production app?** Why is the child-process approach not working in App Engine? Must I use Task queues?

**Task Queue:**
I have also tried task queue after the problem above but I cannot differentiate between task queue handler endpoint and my server's endpoint since [this official doc](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-handlers) also indicates that the handler is also listening to a port, just like my pre-existing `app.js` entry point.

So does it mean that the same `app.js` is the task queue's entry point too?

or does it mean that task queue entry point is another "server" in app engine?

For hours I haven't found a clear guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several trial and error with task queues, I found out it's the same *app.js* which is the same endpoint receiving the task queue calls.